# use dynamic div on animated collapse

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm using the animated collapse JS library here:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/animatedcollapse.htm

and i'm trying to use it for dynamic div's however it's not toggling. Any ideas?

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/animatedcollapse.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?PHP
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) { ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
animatedcollapse.addDiv('location-<?PHP echo $i; ?>', 'fade=1')
</script>

<div id="location-<?PHP echo $i; ?>">
<a href="javascript:animatedcollapse.hide('location-<?PHP echo $i;?>')">CLOSE</a>
TEST
</div>

<a href="javascript:animatedcollapse.toggle('location-<?PHP echo $i;?>')">TOGGLE</a>
<?PHP } ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
animatedcollapse.ontoggle=function($, divobj, state){}
animatedcollapse.init()
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong, but it doesn't seem necessary to use PHP just to create an incrementing variable.

You could just write that same for loop in javascript, inside your script tags: I also think using jQuery's [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) might make this easier for you... Maybe something along these lines:

```
for (var i = 1, i <= 5, i++ ){
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('divToBeToggled' + i).click(function(){
    $('divToBeRevealed' + i).slideToggle('slow');
   });
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just looking quickly at the link you supplied, doesn't this script depend on jQuery also being present?  You don't seem to have that script tag in your head tag.